# How does google produce their animated memes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Google is well known for having many Easter egg embedded into their main services:

1. [Do a barell roll](https://www.google.ht/search?hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Do%20the%20barell%20roll&btnK=#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=Do%20a%20barrel%20roll&oq=Do%20a%20barrel%20roll&gs_l=serp.3...4111.4111.3.4371.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.Ndv7EaZ5KDE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.b2I&fp=548854122be17fbe&biw=1366&bih=667)
2. [Zerg rush](https://www.google.ht/search?hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Do%20the%20barell%20roll&btnK=#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=wb1OznfBHM677aeGXUKKrA&pq=do%20a%20barrel%20roll&cp=4&gs_id=21&xhr=t&q=zerg%20rush&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&oq=Zurg&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.b2I&fp=548854122be17fbe&biw=1366&bih=667)
3. ...

They also have the same thing for the animated Doodle or Google play music intro website.

I was really impressed without being to curious about the technology behind it until recently when they released the  [**do the Harlem shake**](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=do%20the%20harlem%20shake&oq=do%20t&gs_l=youtube.1.0.35i39j0i3j0j0i3j0l6.1669.2332.0.4098.4.4.0.0.0.0.525.1399.0j1j1j0j1j1.4.0...0.0...1ac.1.lALL8oQ8buQ) one :

All the HTML elements behaved like regular HTML elements (a:hover, click...)  apart that they where being distorted.

My guess is that they are using HTML5 with JavaScript, but I wanted to know, **do they have e specific engine/library/software** (like [Adobe Edge](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/)) ?

Or more precisely how is it done?

Comment: I am interested in this too, its extremely well done, smooth and seamlessly integrated into the search page.

Comment: Did you look at the code for the page?

Comment: yes i tried to look at the codes they change dinamically and i can t seem to find what does what

Comment: i tried pretty_printing the css and the js it wan' t clear enough

Comment: Mostly `translateX` & `rotate` as far as I can see. Just add the classes with the css3 animations & go.

Comment: For your inspecting pleasure: [the css](https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-search-shake-vfl9a_m0x.css)

Comment: @Wrikken 100% true, i did process the css in the exemples with http://procssor.com and your comment is good. But in some case i suspect them to use an 'editor' like Adobe Edge to generate it, unless the code all the thing themslef. in the exemple of Zergs Rush the zergs seem to behave in an automated way... but i guess it' s just that no js engines was used

Comment: Well, if you keep in mind that most of that file is `-vendor`-specific prefixes crap, it's actual content isn't that big. But hey, could be generated, I wouldn't see the point for this.

Comment: Looks hand coded to me. The Zerg rush looks like a proof of concept page I did several years ago.